# ClassCastException when trying to lookup XADataSource

Tags: java, jdbc, websphere

I have a servlet WebSphere 8.5 where I am trying to lookup an XADataSource.  However, I get this exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcDataSource incompatible with javax.sql.XADataSource"
```

This is how I lookup the datasource:

```
private String getName(String fromCls, String listCls, String id ) throws Exception {
  InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();
  // ClassCastException happens here
  XADataSource ds = (XADataSource)ctx.lookup("jdbc/DBXA");

  XAConnection dsxaconn = ds.getXAConnection();
  Connection con = dsxaconn.getConnection();
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is an easy thing to get confused. XADataSource is only meant for the application server to use internally.

In your application code, you should just use `javax.sql.DataSource`, and in the WebSphere configuration select XADataSource (which you may have already done).

When your DataSource is configured to be an XADataSource, the application server will automatically call `getXAConnection().getConnection()` when the type is configured to XADataSource.

Comment: I tried your recommendation. It is clear that script don't throw the exception. But it is not seems that application gets XAConnection.

Comment: correct.  The application server exposes neither XADataSource nor XAConnection.  Just use the Connection instead of XAConnection.  It will be XA capable if it came from an XA-configured datasource.

Comment: It was exactly what i did but it didn't help :-(
 InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();
 DataSource ds = (DataSource)ctx.lookup("jdbc/DSXA"); 
 Connection dsconn = ds.getConnection();
I think it is applicatoin server problem.
I used DriverManager and now it work correct.

Comment: What is the new error? Did you still get a classcastexception? You shouldn't, because wsjdbcdatasource implements javax.sql.DataSource. Using driver manager is bad because it bypasses the application server jdbc layer, so at that point you mind as well just run javaSE

Comment: It is don't throw any exception now but the new problem is associated with
other application what wraps my code. So I have to use driver manager in this case. Thank you for you help.